# SSIS, what is causing the slow performance?

Tags: performance, ssis, bulkinsert

For Source: OLE DB Source - Sql Command

```
SELECT -- The destination table Id has IDENTITY(1,1) so I didn't take it here
       [GsmUserId]
      ,[GsmOperatorId]
      ,[SenderHeader]
      ,[SenderNo]
      ,[SendDate]
      ,[ErrorCodeId]
      ,[OriginalMessageId]
      ,[OutgoingSmsId]
      ,24 AS [MigrateTypeId] --This is a static value
  FROM [MyDb].[migrate].[MySource] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

---

To Destination: OLE DB Destination

[image]

Takes 5 or more minutes to insert 1.000.000 data. I even **unchecked** `Check Constraints`

Then, with the **same** SSIS configurations I wanted to test it with another table exactly the same as the Destination table. So, I **re-create** the **destination** table (with the same constrains except the inside data) and named as `dbo.MyDestination`.

But it takes about 30 seconds or less to complete the SAME data with the same amount of Data.
Why is it significantly faster with the test table and not the original table? Is it because the original table already has 107.000.000 data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for indexes/triggers/constraints etc. on your destination table. These may slow things down considerably.

Check OLE DB connection manager's Packet Size, set it appropriately, you can follow [this article](http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/ssis-fastest-data-flow-task-item-for-transferring-data-over-the-network/) to set it to right value.

If you are familiar with of SQL Server Profiler, then use it to get more insight especially what happens when you use re-created table to insert data against original table.

Comment: YES! YES! The article you provided definitely helped! Thank you!